# PayPal payouts sandbox is giving AUTHORIZATION_ERROR

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am using PayPal payouts sandbox API. In my sandbox app, payouts are enabled. But when I hit the API endpoint then it gives `AUTHORIZATION_ERROR` although my `client_id` & `client_secret` are correct. Following is the code sample:

```
function get_paypal_auth_token($client_id, $client_secret) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id.":".$client_secret);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($result);
}

function create_paypal_payment($data) {
    $client_id = "XXXXXX";
    $client_secret = "XXXXXXXSECRET";
    $auth_data = get_paypal_auth_token($client_id, $client_secret);
    $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts";
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$auth_data->access_token));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($resp);
}
```

The expected result of this API should be kind of related to payouts.

Also, I try it with another account's credentials then it gives `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` error.

So can anyone please tell how to add balance to my PayPal account?

Comment: Add money to your `pay pal sandbox account`

Comment: @Amandeep You should not post your credentials here! ***Recommend you change your client tokens right away!!*** Removing them from the post only does so much, they are still stored in revisions. ***Regenerate them***.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add money in your `sandbox account`

1. Login to your Paypal sandbox using your sandbox account.
2. Click My Account –> Add Money
3. Click the type of account
4. Enter the amount

Comment: can you provide me the url on which I should I log into sandbox account. Currently I am logging in here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus/ and its not showing anything like add money option.

Comment: Go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ and click on `profile` link of buyer account then go to `funding` and `add money` to your account

Comment: I tried it using GBP currency also. still same response

Comment: Also I see that there is no option to add money to facilitator account to which the app is connected. Also why do I need to add balance to buyer account as I need to send money from facilitator account. I am not getting whats going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this error only sometimes? I think their sandbox is experiencing issues, as my system also gets this error about 50% of the time since a couple of days ago. You can try sending a direct request to their servers to confirm this.

Comment: I tried sending direct api request here: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts

Comment: And what was the response? If you send it several times, do some of the requests succeed and others don't?

Comment: every time I got AUTHORIZATION_ERROR.